# PCI USB 3.0 cards supported by Linux?

Tags: usb, pci, 16.04

Could someone point me to a USB 3.0 PCI (not PCI-E) card that works with Ubuntu 16.04 and is cheap?

The only ones I've found are 40-50 pounds and the compatibility is unknown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question.

Comment: It is also a question about if there are any compatible cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is barely a market for PCI USB 3.0 cards, probably that's why prices are high. PCI as commonly distributed in the 32-bit at 33 MHz version only supports transmission of 133MB/s, which means pretty much 1000Mbit/s. Subtracting some overhead for the protocol, this already gets pretty close to the maximum speed of 430Mbit/s of USB 2.0. USB 3.0 would allow up to 5Gbit/s, far beyond PCI's capabilities. Don't expect any major improvement in transmission speed comparable to PCIe cards! Even a single USB 3.0 port will be able to occupy the link, which is of course shared among all USB ports on the card.

A quick survey on PCI USB 3.0 cards reveals most of them is running the VIA VL80x chipsets, which is told to be supported by Linux since quite some years. As this is a PCIe chipset, there *might* be some issues because of PCI-PCIe bridge chips, but those are likely also supported well.